# How to query subcollection inside transaction in firebase?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a subcollection named `requests` inside my root collection `tradeRequests`

I want to query my `requests` subcollection using transactions in firebase

This code below will fail because `Transaction.get() requires its first argument to be a DocumentReference`

```
const getOne = (itemID) => db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
  const tradeRequestItemRef = tradeRequestsRef.doc(itemID);
  const requestsRef = tradeRequestItemRef.collection('requests');

  const rawTradeRequestItem = await transaction.get(tradeRequestItemRef);

  if (!rawTradeRequestItem) return null;

  // something like this ???
  // But this line will break everything
  // Error: Transaction.get() requires its first argument to be a DocumentReference
  const rawRequests = transaction.get(requestsRef);

  return {
    ...normalizeData(rawTradeRequestItem),
    requests: normalizeData(rawRequests),
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web and mobile client SDKs, you can't transact on the results of a query within that same transaction. You can only get() each document individually using a DocumentReference.  So, what you can do instead is perform the query first, then `get()` each individual document reference from that query in the transaction to make sure it is being operated on atomically.

```
// query for requests before the transaction
const requests = await db.collection("requests").get()

await db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    // get each document individually again in the transaction
    const requestsInTransaction = []
    for (const doc of requests.docs) {
        const requestInTransaction = await transction.get(doc.ref)
        requestsInTransaction.push(requestInTransaction)
    }

    // Work with each document as needed...
    return whatever_you_want
})
```

Note that if the results of the original query change during the transaction, any new or removed documents will not be seen by the transaction.

Comment: In the last sentence, you said that the changes of the original query when the transaction runs won't be seen by the transaction. Then.... what's the entire point of even using transactions in collections?!

Comment: @dontdownvoteme For client apps, transactions require that you know each document that you want to transact on at the time of the transaction.  This is actually a very common situation.  Transacting on an entire collection or query results (which could be huge) would be a performance problem.

Comment: what about server-side? If you run a query transaction, would that ensure that the collection will not change until the transaction is completed?

Comment: @dontdownvoteme No, you can only ensure that up to 500 individual documents do not change.  If you get those from a query against a collection, fine.  But it is still going to be just 500 max in order to prevent performance and scalability issues.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention?authuser=0) on "Transaction serializability and isolation" for Firestore, **the mobile/web SDKs (iOS, Android, Web, C++) use optimistic concurrency controls**.

The doc explains that:

> The transaction keeps track of all the documents you read inside the
> transaction ... and completes its write operations **only if** none of
> those documents changed during the transaction's execution. If any
> document did change, the transaction handler retries the transaction.
> If the transaction can't get a clean result after a few retries, the
> transaction fails due to data contention.

So the risk of having too many data contention failures when keeping track of all the documents returned by a Query is considered too high, therefore the mobile/web SDKs do not give the possibility to execute a Query in a Transaction.

---

On the other hand, **the Admin SDKs use pessimistic concurrency controls**, therefore you can execute a query within a Transaction and place a  pessimistic lock on all the documents returned by the Query. So one solution is to use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0) (which uses the Admin SDK) and call this Cloud Function from your Client.

More concretely, you would use, in your Cloud Function, the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get) method from the Node.js Server SDK for Google Cloud Firestore, which can be passed a [`Query`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html) and will hold a pessimistic lock on all returned documents.